# Foreign keys from 2 columns of the same table to the same primary key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables:

**users**

```
id  |  username
--------------
 1  |  James
 2  |  John
 3  |  Jack
 4  |  Jim
 5  |  Jane
 6  |  Jessica
```

**juniors**

```
senior_id  |  junior_id
-----------------------
 1         |  4
 1         |  6
 2         |  3
 4         |  5
```

Both the `senior_id` and `junior_id` refer to the `users` table's `id` column.

How do I set it up so that a) it is guaranteed that both `senior_id` and `junior_id` exist in `users` and b) a `delete` from `users` will cascade and remove any instances of the deleted id from `juniors` whether it's a `senior_id` or `junior_id`? I.e. deleting Jim in the example above will automatically remove both the first and last record from juniors.

I tried doing this with two separate constraints. But if I set up cascade on both constraints I get a 'may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths' error.

And if I set it on only one constraint then a delete fails (in a case like Jim) because it cascades to only one of the columns and thus then violates the constraint.

I have to be able to do this on SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Remove FK constraint.For FK constraint check.Create  trigger on table juniors before insert/update.if id do not exists then rollback.Again now create another trigger on table User for DELETE.and in trigger write script to delete all record.since FK do not fulfill your requirement,therefore no point in keeping one extra constraint.

Most importantly I think your table design is bad.Table design should be like Employee-Manager relation table i.e. keep SeniorID in User Table itself.

so many of your problem will vanish .
Also there is no extra cost or complication for any query on this table

```
id  |  username   SeniorID
--------------
 1  |  James
 2  |  John
 3  |  Jack        2
 4  |  Jim         5 
 5  |  Jane
 6  |  Jessica
```

Comment: Thanks and I understand what you say about the table design. Unfortunately I'm dealing with a many-to-many relationship, i.e. in this case a junior can have more than one senior. So including that in the users table won't work here.

Comment: oh ! it won't work in many to many relation.Then Creating 2 trigger is best option.